# Vue mapState object is mutating vuex state

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

I have very strange problem, because this one doesnt show up in Quasar when developing electron app. But this one with vue-cli is frustrating.

So I have vuex state, where I have my test data

```
export default function() {
  return {
    profile: {
      avatar: null,
      name: 'Thomas Smith',
      contact: 'thomas.smith@bootiq.io',
      branch: 'BIQ-PRAGUE',
      position: 'Software Developer / UI Designer',
      projects: [
        {
          company: 'Company',
          project: 'E-Shop Platform',
          role: 'Frontend Developer, Consultant'
        },
        {
          company: 'BIQ-INTERNAL',
          project: 'Skillboard',
          role: 'UI Design, Project Lead'
        }
      ],
      interests: ['Frontend Applications', 'UI Design', 'Stalking random people'],
      skills: [
        {
          name: 'Javascript',
          level: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'Vue',
          level: 3
        },
        {
          name: 'Angular',
          level: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

now I have component for editing profile data

```
computed: {
    ...mapState({
      stateSkillList: state => state.skill.skillList
    }),

    ...mapGetters({
      user: 'user/getUser'
    })
  },

  mounted() {
    if (this.user) {
      this.data = Object.assign({}, this.data, this.user)

      if (this.data.projects.length === 0) {
        this.data.projects = [this.baseItems.projects]
      }

      if (this.data.skills.length) {
        this.filterSkillList()
      }
    }
  },
```

now my problem. I have inputs where v-model is data.name, data.contact etc and everything works fine. But when I tried to add/remove skill from data.skill array or from data.projects, data.interests, I get

```
vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue.esm.js?a026:628
logError @ vue.esm.js?a026:1893
globalHandleError @ vue.esm.js?a026:1888
handleError @ vue.esm.js?a026:1848
run @ vue.esm.js?a026:4579
update @ vue.esm.js?a026:4551
notify @ vue.esm.js?a026:739
mutator @ vue.esm.js?a026:891
handleRemoveSkill @ EditProfile.vue?05c4:306
click @ EditProfile.vue?0ae8:411
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.esm.js?a026:1863
invoker @ vue.esm.js?a026:2188
original._wrapper @ vue.esm.js?a026:7565
vue.esm.js?a026:1897 Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
    at assert (vuex.esm.js?2f62:90)
    at Vue.store._vm.$watch.deep (vuex.esm.js?2f62:814)
    at Watcher.run (vue.esm.js?a026:4577)
    at Watcher.update (vue.esm.js?a026:4551)
    at Dep.notify (vue.esm.js?a026:739)
    at Array.mutator (vue.esm.js?a026:891)
    at VueComponent.handleRemoveSkill (EditProfile.vue?05c4:306)
    at click (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"6bb1df4e-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/EditProfile.vue?vue&type=template&id=7b259475&scoped=true& (app.js:1178), <anonymous>:414:44)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.esm.js?a026:1863)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.esm.js?a026:2188)
```

and I have no idea why. Here is simple function

```
handleAddSkill(name) {
  this.data.skills.push({ name })
  this.dataSkillFilteredList = this.dataSkillFilteredList.filter(item => item !== name)
  this.dataSkillList = this.dataSkillFilteredList
},
```

Thank you for your ideas

Comment: Your question can't be answered without a [mcve] and what you posted so far is not enough to create one. If you need a multi-file node environment, use codesandbox.io or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You've copied the state and trying to change that copy. That's why vuex is warning you. By doing that the components that depend on that particular vuex state will not get the new data you've updated because you're **mutating** outside of the vuex store and editing its copy. If you're really want to change the state, you should do it inside that vuex store with its **mutation functions** which will really update the original state. Vuex even allow you to directly update the vuex state without mutation functions (like setting vuex computed property to v-model). Because it also updates the original state (however wrongly). But the way you're doing doesn't affect the original **vuex store** at all and vuex doesn't seem to like that. So, the solutions is to use the **mutation functions** but if you're data is too much to handle you can just change the computed property directly with **getters** and **setters** (hell, you don't even have to use **getters** and **setters**). The first way is ***preferred***.

Comment: but when Im typing to inputs, where v-model="data.name", nothing bad happened and vuex is same, but this.data, object in component, is changing like it should, also I used Object.assign to create separate object, so I dont have idea why its not working and yes, I want to change vuex state but after submiting my changes

Comment: so how can I make that copy of state and safely change it?

Comment: Like I said, it's just a warning. You can ignore it. But if you don't want to ignore it, here's what I did to solve that problem. I directly changed the computed property of vuex store. And until the user click the save button, I'd hold of the backend request to save. If the user didn't click the save button but instead clicked cancel button, I'd request my original data once again from the api: making every the way it was.